# Calculating KKT coefficients

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am wondering if my code is good 100%, because in my alghoritm it is stated that when you remove the constraints with KKT coefficient equal to zero, then it won't change the result of optimization, unfortunately it changes. The task is to calculate KKT coefficients, which satisfy KKT conditions:

[image]

```
function [v]= KKTpz(x)
        global Sk g f
        n = length(x);
        m = size(Sk,1);
        F_S = @(k) sum(k.^2);
        % Create A and B %% 
        Aeq_v = [];
        h =0.00001;
        for j = 1:m
            Aeq_v(1,j) = 0;
            for m1 = 1:n
                vec = zeros(1,n);
                vec(m1) = h;
                Aeq_v(1,j) = Aeq_v(1,j) + (g(x + vec, Sk(j,:)) - g(x, Sk(j,:)))/(h);
            end
        end
        %Aeq is a gradient g with respect to x in points s_i 
        beq_v = zeros(1);
        for m1 = 1:n
                vec = zeros(1,n);
                vec(m1) = h;
                beq_v(1) = beq_v(1) -(f(x + vec) - f(x))/(h);
        end
        %beq is minus gradient f(x)
        k = 2;
        for i = 1:m
            if abs(g(x, Sk(i,:)))>10^-4 % Check if g(x, s) == 0
                Aeq_v(k,:) = 0;
                Aeq_v(k,i) = 1;
                beq_v = [beq_v,0];
                k = k+1;
            end
        end
        % if g(x,s_i) is not equal to zero
        % then v(s_i) must be equal zero 
        v = fmincon(F_S,ones(size(Sk,1),1),[],[], Aeq_v, beq_v,zeros(m,1),[]); % Define v
end
```

Comment: Add more comments to your code so that we can follow you

Comment: I updated the code (added some comments), basically Aeq contains first equality in KKT conditions and g(x,s_i)v(s_i)=0 .

Comment: The way you expose your algorithm only you can understand. First, instead of providing a function you should provide a simple procedural algorithm where   you  define `x`, `Sk` everything then find an actual result. Later you can state your expected result. Not everyone on SO know about `KKT`, I do but my algorithm is completely different than yours. I mainly use `solve()` to find `KKT coefficients lambda` then I pick the ones satisfying KKT conditions. About the coefficient equal to zero you may read more on `active and inactive constraints`. Understand the meaning first is important.